# How to make stdcall from Go

Tags: com, go, stdcall, cgo

I have a pointer to a COM interface and would like to take the function pointers from its virtual table and make method calls. To do this I need to make stdcall method calls. In Go how do I make a call with convention stdcall or make a call with convention stdcall in cgo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "godoc syscall Proc" for instructions on how to call stdcall functions on windows. Be warned that *Proc.Call does allocate / deallocate memory, so, if you care about efficiency, you should use correspondent syscall.Syscall/syscall.Syscall6/syscall.Syscall9/... function instead.

Alex

Comment: If I'm making a normal function call with stdcall calling conventions that is not a system call, how does it make sense to use Syscall()?

Comment: syscall.Syscall is platform specific. On windows it uses stdcall convention to call functions inside of dlls. See http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/syscall/zsyscall_windows_386.go for many examples of how to do it.